# Show a UserForm that matches the contents of a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

On my spreadsheet, cell E8 will contain the name of a UserForm. For this example "mainMenu".

On my UserForm "newClient", when the button "btnAddClient" is clicked, I'd like to unload the "newClient" form and show whichever form matches the name that is shown in cell E8.

I've tried the following different code but none work. How can this be done?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Text.Show
ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Value.Show
ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you will know upfront which user forms are in your excel spreadsheet.
Try something like this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim formName As String
    formName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E8").Value

    Select Case formName
    Case "UserForm1"
        UserForm1.Show
    Case "UserForm2"
        UserForm2.Show
    End Select

End Sub
```